# Tengo un error al crear un paquete en Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, studio

buenas noches, recientemente estoy empezando con android studio viendo clases en platzi, el que dicta las clases crea un paquete dentro de com.example.aplicacion y no le pasa nada, al crearlo yo, me sale el siguiente error:

[image: Error]

Estas vendrian a ser mis modificaciones en los archivos

[image: Archivos]

Y cuando yo apreto en "Show in project structure dialog" me lleva a las siguientes dependencias:

[image: Dependencias]

Muchisimas gracias a toda ayuda.
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer estas importando una librería que no existe ( según los logs). Puede que se te haya pasado un copy paste. en la última imagen tienes la dependencia llamada `androidx.navigation:navigation-com-example-myapplication.ui-ktx:2.1.0`. Lo que puedes intentar es remover esa dependencia y  hacer un sync ( el icono de Android Studio que parece un elefante). Entiendo que estas utilizando `navigation fragment` y esa dependencia si esta bien escrita `androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.1.0` pero la otra que es `androidx.navigation:navigation-com-example-myapplication.ui-ktx:2.1.0` parece que no existe y te esta causando conflictos.

Espero te ayude :)

Answer (score 0):

El error indica que no puede encontrar la dependencia, en realidad en realidad la definición es incorreta:

> Failed to resolve:
> androidx.navigation:navigation-com.example.myapplication.ui.ktx:2.1.0

La correcta definición de la dependencia que debe ser agregada dentro del `build.gradle` en el bloque `dependencies` es:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.1.0"
}
```

Revisa la [documentación oficial de AndroidX Navigation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#safeargs)